# WSLD file that refers to XML schema which imports another XML schema

Tags: xsd, wsdl, w3c

Our service contract is composed of a wsdl file (W) and several XSDs (A,B,C).

Basically W refers to A, which is just an empty schema that imports B and C.

Our client claims that such structure is against the W3C specs and that B and C must be explicitly imported by W.

Our solution validates against XML Spy, SOAP UI and works well with Java.

Do you know if their claim is correct?

Comment: It's not a violation of the XSD spec; I can't speak for the WSDL spec.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it seems that it does violate the XSD spec. Apparently, if:
schema A refers to schema B and C it  does not matter whether schema B imports schema C or not, A must import B and C.

At least, that's what I have found googling around and the W3c specs seem to say so as well.

Comment: Can you provide a link to and a quote from the W3C spec that states that it is a violation?